# Can statistical inferences be made on "any" probability distribution?

Tags: r, probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I have always seen statistical inferences being made on "clean and exact" probability distributions - for example, (multivariate) normal distributions. But can statistical inferences be made on "rough and irregular" probability distributions? I tried to illustrate my question using the R programming language:

Suppose we have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
var_1 = rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
var_2 = rnorm(1000, 5, 10)
my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2)

head(my_data)
      var_1      var_2
1  7.197622  -4.957987
2  8.849113  -5.399550
3 17.793542   4.820198
4 10.352542   3.678249
5 10.646439 -20.493428
6 18.575325  15.405735
```

I can try and estimate the probability distribution for this data using two different methods: [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) and [mixture models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model).

**1) Kernel density estimates**

Using R, we can estimate the multivariate kernel density estimate of this data and generate a probability distribution function:

```
# Load library
library(ks)

# Perform kernel density estimate (choose arbitrary bandwidth parameters)

H <- diag(c(1.25, 0.75))
kde <- ks::kde(x = my_data, H = H)

# Plot the results
image(kde$eval.points[[1]], kde$eval.points[[2]], kde$estimate,
      col = viridis::viridis(20), xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
points(kde$x) # The data is returned in $x
```

[image]

```
library(plotly)

kd <- with(my_data, MASS::kde2d(my_data$var_1, my_data$var_2, n = 50))

 plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

*I am not sure if it is possible to evaluate how well this kernel density estimate (i.e., the choice of the bandwidth/smoothing parameters) fits the data (e.g., aic, bic, and likelihood)* - in reality, we would fit multiple kernel density estimates to this same data using different choices of kernels, smoothing and bandwidth parameters. The final kernel density estimate would create a probability distribution function of the following form:

[image]

**2) Mixture models**

Another popular approach is to fit (Gaussian) mixture models to this data:

```
library(mclust)

# Fit mixture model with two components:
mod1 <- Mclust(my_data, G = 2)
```

[image]

```
  summary(mod1, parameters = TRUE)
```

We can see the results of the mixture:

```
 summary(mod1, parameters = TRUE)
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust EEI (diagonal, equal volume and shape) model with two components:

 log-likelihood    n df       BIC      ICL
      -6747.084 1000  7 -13542.52 -14181.7

Clustering table:
  1   2
750 250

Mixing probabilities:
        1         2
0.6613209 0.3386791

Means:
          [,1]     [,2]
var_1 9.438299 11.33490
var_2 2.250080 11.62347

Variances:
[,,1]
         var_1    var_2
var_1 23.75622  0.00000
var_2  0.00000 82.16364
[,,2]
         var_1    var_2
var_1 23.75622  0.00000
var_2  0.00000 82.16364
```

The log-likelihood of this fitted mixture model (assume no covariances) is  **-6747.084**, and the general form of this model is: **0.66 * Bivariate_Normal (mean = (9.4, 2.2), variance = (23.75622, 82)) + 0.33 * Bivariate_Normal (mean = (11.3, 11.6), variance = (23.7, 82))**

I am not sure if my understanding of multivariate theory is correct, but I have plotted (what I think is) the mixture model (i.e., the resulting probability distribution):

```
library(bivariate)

bivar <- bmbvpdf (
    mean.X1 = 0.66*9.4 + 0.33*11, mean.X2 = 0.66*2.2 + 0.33*11.6,

    sd.X1 = sqrt(0.66* 23 + 0.33 * 82), sd.X2 = sqrt(0.66* 23 + 0.33 * 82),
)

plot(bivar)
```

[image]

If once the probability distribution function for some data is estimated using kernel density estimates or by mixture models, can we use these resulting probability distributions for statistical inference? Is it even possible to take the kernel density estimate and find the conditional probability distribution (e.g., Prob(x1 given x2 = c))?

Comment: Note: I was trying to find if there exist any evaluation metrics which can be used to check how well the kernel density estimate fits the data (e.g. bic, aic, likelihood). I found a useful link over here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kedd/vignettes/kedd.pdf . Has anyone ever heard of evaluation metrics for kernel density estimates? thanks!

Comment: what kind of statistical inference do you have mind? could you go into more detail?

Comment: Yes. In fact some tests are based on empirical distribution functions. Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, for example. Contingency table tests, for categorical data for another.

Comment: You could use a permutation test to see if two empirical distributions that seem to have similar shapes have different means, different variances, etc. You could use a nonparametric bootstrap confidence interval to estimate the mean of a single univariate empirical distribution.

Comment: thank you everyone for your replies!

Comment: Warning: A mixture of two Normal distributions is not a Normal distribution.

Answer (score 3):

You have some very nice graphics in your question.
I am not entirely sure I understand exactly what each illustrates
in terms of your main question.

Ignoring that your two variables are sampled from
normal distributions, I want to do an elementary
exploration these two samples: (a) Are they distinguishable
by standard tests. (b) If they are mixed, what is the
mean of the mixture. A few of the methods and challenges of
doing statistical inference on data from unknown
population types are discussed briefly.

(a)

A Kolmogorov-Smirnov test finds a clear difference
between the two samples. This test is notorious for low power,
but we have large enough samples that it is useful

```
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(1000,10,5)
x2 = rnorm(1000,5,10)
ks.test(x1, x2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x1 and x2
D = 0.33, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The test statistic of the K-S test is the largest vertical
distance between the empirical CDFs of the two samples.

```
hdr = "ECDF Plots of Samples 1 (blue) and 2"
plot(ecdf(x2), col="brown", main=hdr)
lines(ecdf(x1), col="blue")
```

[image]

A Welch 2-sample t test shows a highly significant
difference in means, and an F-test shows a highly significant
difference in variances. If data are nearly normal the Welch test is
valid (especially on account of the moderately large sample size).
The F test is not at all robust against departures from normality.

```
t.test(x1, x2)$p.val
[1] 4.329103e-37

var.test(x1, x2)$p.val
[1] 1.202862e-103
```

(b)

Mix the two samples to obtain a single sample `x` of size $n=1000.$
Because the difference in locations of `x1` and `x2` is small
compared to their variances, the mixture in unimodal.

```
set.seed(1016)
x = sample(c(x1, x2), 1000)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-21.040   3.278   8.668   7.676  12.710  38.904 
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Confidence intervals of the mean (t interval) and median (Wilcoxon)
of the mixture distribution. Both styles of confidence interval
are questionable: the t interval $(7.17, 8.19)$ for the mean because the
mixture distribution is not normal, and the nonparametric interval
$(7.57, 8.54)$ for the median because the mixture distribution is not symmetrical.

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 7.165765 8.185229
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

wilcox.test(x, conf.int=T)$conf.int
[1] 7.568812 8.538802
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

One style of 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI $(7.19, 8.17)$ is shown below,
it is similar to the t interval.

```
a.obs = mean(x); a.obs
[1] 7.675497
re.d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(x,1000,rep=T))-a.obs)
LU = quantile(re.d, c(.975,.025))
a.obs - LU
   97.5%     2.5% 
7.186136 8.166439
```